# React-router Link Changes URL ID but Component Does Not Reload

Tags: reactjs

I use Link to redirect a list of items to another detail component. But now the URL changes with the selected IDs but the detail component does not called. Please help with my react-router issue. Below is my code:

````
```
index.js
 <BrowserRouter>
   <Switch>
      <Route path='/' component={App} />
      <Route path='/course/:ID' component={CourseDetail} />
   </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
````

```js
  CourseList.js
    
           
            const CourseList=({Courses})=>{
             //map list
            const renderedList= Courses.map(course=>{
                return (<div>
            
                <div class="content">
                <Link  to={{ pathname: 'course/'+course.ID}}                    
                                    key={course.ID}>
                                    View More
                                </Link>    
                </div>
                </div> 
            )
            });
            return (
            <Router><div>
                {renderedList}
                <Route path="course/:ID" component={CourseDetail} />
            </div></Router>);
            }
            export default CourseList;
        
CourseDetail.js

           
            class CourseDetail extends Component {
              state={
                 ID: this.props.match.params.ID,
                 course:null};
                componentDidMount(){
                 //this.runSearch only get called when URL loads, but not when Link        //clicked
                  this.runSearch();
                
               }
              
               runSearch=async()=>{
             
                 const response= await axios.get('API\?{this.props.match.params.ID}')
                 this.setState({course: response.data});
              
               }
            render(){
               //course is null below
            //const course=this.state.course;
           
            return (
               <div>
                Course Detail: ID {this.props.match.params.ID}
            </div>
            ); }   
            };
            export default withRouter(CourseDetail);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the attribute `exact` for your `indexRoute`, otherwise for even `/course/:ID` route it will still match with `/` .

Can you please update your **`index.js`** file as below.

```
 <BrowserRouter>
   <Switch>
      <Route exact path='/' component={App} />
      <Route path='/course/:ID' component={CourseDetail} />
   </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Hope this will work for you!

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help! I added exact path for {App} in the index.js and removed the Router in the CourseList.js and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the order of the `Route` declarations. `<Switch>` returns the first matching route and since your first route is for `/`, that's the one will be returned even though URL is for course detail with ID.

```
<Route path='/course/:ID' component={CourseDetail} />
<Route path='/' component={App} />
```

Or, You can also put `exact` in your default route. like,

```
<Route exact path='/' component={App} />
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are using two different routers.

Add `exact` for the `/` route.

```
 <BrowserRouter>
   <Switch>
      <Route exact path='/' component={App} />
      <Route path='/course/:ID' component={CourseDetail} />
   </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

```
return (
            <React.Fragment>
                {renderedList}
            </React.Fragment>
)
```